# К комментарию самопроизвольно добавился мой голос за и не снимается

Tags: дефект, комментарии, голоса-за

К [комметарию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681863/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83#comment1000637_681863) самопроизвольно добавился мой голос "за" и никак не снимается.

Comment: Ответ удален. Скорее всего он был удален, пока у вас была открыта страница. Голоса на удаленных ответах и комментариях к ним блокируются.

Comment: @PashaPash Он был удалён через минут 10-15 пока у меня висел мой голос и никак не снимался. В этом я уверен на 100%. Если у вас есть возможность проверить по времени удаления и сверить с временем создания этого вопроса на мете, то вы в этом убедитесь.